# Unity - Register Interface that accepts Type <T>

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, unity-container

Using Unity, I am trying to register the following interface to a model:

```
public interface IGenericRepository<T> : IDisposable where T : class
```

Is this the correct way to register this within Unity's Bootstrapper?

```
            container.RegisterType<IGenericRepository<TypeBasedOverride>, GenericRepository<TypeBasedOverride>>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
```

Comment: And what is behind the question? With no additional contex, the answer could just be "yes".

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to register that interface for any concrete T.
If so, you need to register the generic types as open generic types (without the type arguments). Check this [msdn entry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660936%28PandP.20%29.aspx).

In your example:

```
container.RegisterType(typeof(IGenericRepository<>), typeof(GenericRepository<>), new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
```

This way when you request an instance of `IGenericRepository<SomeClass>`, Unity will provide you with an instance of `GenericRepository<SomeClass>`, no matter the concrete type of SomeClass.